# Generate random in [0, n)

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Using `<random>` standard functions/classes/etc of C++11 how to generate random number in these ranges:

- (*n*, *m*) - not including both ends
- (*n*, *m*] - not including beginning
- [*n*, *m*) - not including end

And special cases of them:

- [0, *n*)
- [0, 1)

Or may be there is any doc like cheat sheet for `<random>`?

Comment: What kind of distribution do you want? See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: @Michael May be universal solution for any distribution, but if this not possible, for `uniform_int_distribution` or `uniform_real_distribution` (for ranges like [0, 1) )

Comment: If you have x in [0,1) then (1-x) is in (0,1]. Similar for the general case

Comment: Well, `uniform_int_distribution(a, b)` gives you `[a, b]`. So it seems like you could just alter the arguments to get the ranges you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [Uniform Real Distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution)

A [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution) will give values in the range `[a, b)`. We can use [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter) to convert between open and closed ranges.

```
int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());

    // [1, 10]
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_a(1, std::nextafter(10, std::numeric_limits<double>::max));

    // [1, 10)
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_b(1, 10);

    // (1, 10)
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_c(std::nextafter(1, std::numeric_limits<double>::max), 10);

    // (1, 10]
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> dist_d(std::nextafter(1, std::numeric_limits<double>::max), std::nextafter(10, std::numeric_limits<double>::max));

    // Random Number Generators are used like this:
    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        std::cout << dist_d(mt) << "\n";
}
```

#### [Uniform Int Distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution)

A [`uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) will give values in the range `[a, b]`. We can just add and subtract `1` to switch between open and closed ranges.

```
int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());

    // [1, 10]
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_a(1, 10);    

    // [1, 10)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_b(1, 10 - 1); 

    // (1, 10)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_c(1 + 1, 10 - 1); 

    // (1, 10]
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_d(1 + 1, 10);

    // Random Number Generators are used like this:
    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        std::cout << dist_d(mt) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Remark: `std::nextafter` takes two parameters, correct will be (for example for 1) `std::nextafter(1, std::numeric_limits<double>::max)`.

Comment: @vladon: Blah.. For some reason I thought that was an implicit argument.